# Does sleep immunity mean you don't need sleep?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Does sleep immunity imply you do not need to sleep, or simply that you can't be forced to sleep?

I'm specifically trying to figure out what the the alchemist's Mummification discovery means on this point.

Comment: (Note that James Jacobs shuns *Elves of Golarion*'s meditating elves in favor of actual sleeping elves in [this thread](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?262997-Why-do-elves-sleep-now) on the Paizo messageboards.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Mummification discovery says:

> he becomes immune to cold, nonlethal damage, paralysis, and sleep.

Cit. [d20pfsrd.com](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/mummification-ex)

This is a list of things that the character is immune to. "Sleep" means the sleep spell, not that the character lacks a biological need to sleep.

Note that although d20pfsrd.com links to the sleep spell in their wiki, not everyone does.  This is an interpretation of the discovery's text.  However, sleep is not a status condition or damage type, unlike the other entries in the discovery's text.

Compare mummification's text to something like the Construct description:

> Constructs do not breathe, eat, or sleep.
>   Cit.: [d20pfsrd.com](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Construct)

The ability specifically mentions not needing sleep.  Mummification's text does not.